# cabal install hangs installing yesod-platform

Tags: haskell, yesod, cabal-install

The cabal install of yesod-platform hangs downloading xss-sanitize.  NetHogs shows no network activity related to this download.

```
$ cabal install yesod-platform
Resolving dependencies...
Downloading xss-sanitize-0.3.4...
```

Other packages download and install without delay.

I'm on Fedora 18. The haskell-platform and cabal-install are up-to-date from the repos.

```
$ cabal --version
cabal-install version 0.14.0
using version 1.14.0 of the Cabal library

$ ghc --version
The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 7.4.1
```

### Edit

I left it run overnight it seemed to give up on xss-sanitizer, and continued installing the other dependencies.  Here is the tail.

```
...
Configuring yesod-test-1.2.1...
Building yesod-test-1.2.1...
Preprocessing library yesod-test-1.2.1...
[1 of 3] Compiling Yesod.Test.CssQuery ( Yesod/Test/CssQuery.hs, dist/build/Yesod/Test/CssQuery.o )
[2 of 3] Compiling Yesod.Test.TransversingCSS ( Yesod/Test/TransversingCSS.hs, dist/build/Yesod/Test/TransversingCSS.o )
[3 of 3] Compiling Yesod.Test       ( Yesod/Test.hs, dist/build/Yesod/Test.o )

Yesod/Test.hs:113:1:
    Warning: In the use of `runFakeHandler'
             (imported from Yesod.Core, but defined in yesod-core-1.2.4.2:Yesod.Core.Internal.Run):
             "Usually you should *not* use runFakeHandler unless you really understand how it works and why you need it."
Registering yesod-test-1.2.1...
Installing library in /home/smithd/.cabal/lib/yesod-test-1.2.1/ghc-7.4.1

cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
xss-sanitize-0.3.4 failed while downloading the package. The exception was:
<socket: 4>: hGetBufSome: timeout (Connection timed out)
yesod-1.2.2.1 depends on xss-sanitize-0.3.4 which failed to install.
yesod-auth-1.2.2.1 depends on xss-sanitize-0.3.4 which failed to install.
yesod-form-1.3.2.1 depends on xss-sanitize-0.3.4 which failed to install.
yesod-platform-1.2.4.2 depends on xss-sanitize-0.3.4 which failed to install.
[smithd@lin2900 ~]$ cabal install yesod-platform
```

Comment: Have you tried downloading the tar of the package and building/installing it locally?

Comment: Does this happen every time or just occasionally? Also, the 0.14 release is two years old.

Comment: Always the same on this package, but no other packages are effected.  I install on Fedora 19 box on Saturday with no issue.

Comment: @bheklilr - wget http://hackage.haskell.org/package/xss-sanitize-0.3.4/xss-sanitize-0.3.4.tar.gz begin the download but never finishes. Can wget other packages without issue.  Could be my companies filter, but unlikely. Will try from home tonight.

Comment: @dsmith try this link -> https://www.dropbox.com/s/xbho5k3z44p412x/xss-sanitize-0.3.4.tar.gz.  You'll probably have to do it through your browser since it's dropbox.  Alternatively, if you don't trust a random stranger's dropbox link, you can grab it from the developer's github https://github.com/yesodweb/haskell-xss-sanitize.

Comment: Wow.  Must be something strange in the companies internet filter. Can't pull that down either. I'll use githun.

Comment: Same problem here. Same package and all. Did it work at home?

Comment: Yes worked at home.  You may be able to get your network admins to whitelist hackage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My companies internet filter was blocking the haskell-xss-sanitize package as a possible XSS threat.  Specifically the test modules.  Have your admin white-list hackage if possible.